# awk to update record

Tags: bash, awk

I have data in a text file:

```
Customer:HDB:Price:Left:total
Ted 1:rm4:34:197:101
```

I'm trying to update the latest record for left and total to the database. Why doesn't this expression work?

```
awk -F : -v OFS=: -v customer=$customer-v hdb=$hdb \
   -v left=$left -v total=$total \
   '$1==customer && $2==hdb {`$4=left $5=total;`}1' file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you forgot `;` here:

`$4=left; $5=total;`

2) space required here:

`customer=$customer -v`

3) `` not required here:

`{$4=left; $5=total;}`

**This should work:**

```
awk -F : -v OFS=: -v customer="$customer" -v hdb="$hdb" -v left="$left" \
  -v total="$total" '$1==customer && $2==hdb { $4=left; $5=total } 1' file
```

Comment: awk: cannot open -v (No such file or directory)

It doesn't take up whitespace for customer? System will take only Ted and not Ted 1

Comment: @user1745860 You should use `customer="$customer"` variable defenition. ( see edited answer )

Comment: @user1745860, that is supposed to be one single line. I've edited a touch to emphasize that.